# Using dynamic variables to print a color from colorama or any other color module

Tags: python

I want to find a way to assign a dynamic entry of a variable `colorvalue= ' '`, and print the text entry in the color typed, something like:

```
from colorama import Fore

colorval= input('Type your color: ')
print(colorval, Fore.colorval)
```

Then if I type "red", the text is printed in red, and so on with the color typed, does anyone has any clue?

Comment: You can use `Fore.__getattribute__(colorvalue)`, providing `colorvalue` is a member of the `Fore` class.  For example `Fore.RED`.  Just remember to call reset at the end.

Comment: If the value input was a valid attribute of `Fore` (i.e `"RED"`), you could use an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-f-string) and something like `print(f'{getattr(Fore, colorval, Fore.BLACK)} + 'some text')`. Note that the `Fore.BLACK` is a default value to use if the attribute isn't found.

Answer (score 0):

When you write Fore.<something>, that something must be a method of Fore, not a variable.

```
Fore.RED #this is valid

color = 'RED'
Fore.color #results in error - 'color' is not a method of Fore
```

A quick glance at colorama documentation suggests that to do what you are wanting to do, you probably need the Termcolor library:

```
from colorama import init
from termcolor import colored

# use Colorama to make Termcolor work on Windows too
init()

# then use Termcolor for all colored text output
color = input('type in a color').lower()
print(colored(color, color))
```

At least in my environment (VSCode on Windows), I was able to use termcolor without colorama:

```
from termcolor import colored

color = input('Enter a color').lower()
print(colored(color, color))
```

Comment: Thank you guys, the using the termcolor worked smooth!... have a nice day...